# Property 'Queue' cannot be empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

This is my first StackOverflow post, so sorry if the formatting is poor.

I could really use a second pair of eyes on my CloudFormation template. I am currently trying to wire up an SQS to alert whenever any object is created in my S3 bucket. I keep getting the error `Property Queue cannot be empty`, (even though it isn't). I've tried putting the ARN in single quotes, double quotes, no quotes, and nothing works. I have most recently tried to create a QueuePolicy for it and that just made it worse...

```
  rS3SqsTriggerDummy:
    DependsOn: rS3SqsTriggerPolicyQA
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub
          - "${bucketName}"
          - { bucketName: !FindInMap [Stage, !Ref StageName, bucketName]}
      NotificationConfiguration:
          QueueConfigurations:
          - Event: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'
          - Filter: 
                S3Key:
                  Rules:
                      Name: prefix
                      Value: 'dummy/'
            Queue: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:958262988361:interstate-claire-dummy-trigger-qa
```

If someone could take a look and give me some feedback, I'd be eternally grateful! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried reformatting it?

Comment: Looking at the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-notificationconfig-queueconfig.html, Event, Filter and Queue appear to be at the same level. 
  But, you have a dash "-"  in front of "Filter"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AWS::S3::Bucket QueueConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-notificationconfig-queueconfig.html) has the form of:

```
  QueueConfigurations: 
    - QueueConfiguration
```

This means that `QueueConfigurations` is a **list** of `QueueConfiguration`, where `QueueConfiguration` is an **object** with `Event`, `Filter` and `Queue` properties. Thus `QueueConfigurations` should be (note only one `-`):

```
  NotificationConfiguration:
          QueueConfigurations:
            - Event: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'
              Filter: 
                S3Key:
                  Rules:
                    - Name: prefix
                      Value: 'dummy/'
              Queue: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:958262988361:interstate-claire-dummy-trigger-qa
```

Please be careful about **indentation**. Copying and pasting from SO may require reformatting.

Comment: Thanks! I ran it again, and now I'm getting a new error, `Value of property Rules must be of type List` . Does that mean I need a `-` before `Name` as well?

Comment: @ClaireLe Hi. Yes. I updated the answer to add missing `-` :-)